# Power BI grand total on top N wrong percent

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am running in this issue:
I want to display top 5 order on items list, and show the overall %.

[image]

As you can see on the left table, item H has 60 orders and an overall of 21.05%
Now I want to see only the top 5, but with the same % overall and not 28.57% as you can see on the right table.

The filter is pretty easy.

[image]

I guess it can be resolved using DAX, but can't find the correct formula.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implicit measure `%GT orders` is designed to sum to 100%. You'll need to write your own measure if you want it to behave as you describe.

The measure would look something like this:

```
Percent Orders =
DIVIDE(
    SUM(Table1[orders]),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Table1[orders]),
        ALL(Table1)
    )
)
```

The implicit measure `%GT orders` you have is essentially using `ALLSELECTED()` instead of `ALL()`. You want the latter if you want to ignore your top N filter in the denominator.

Comment: What if I have a filter on a date, that I want to keep in my context?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the %GST order is a measure that is calculated based on the data available to it. You might want to add a calculated column with the values calculated based on the data as follows

```
%GST = Table1[Orders]/sum(Table1[Orders])
```

then you might use the filter based on orders and see the data accordingly. See the images below. Hope this helps.

[image: New Column]

[image: reports view]